# JavaScript property access using brackets

Tags: javascript

If I declare the following in my Chrome console:

```
var object = {0:0, 1:1}
```

I can call object[0] and object[1] and get their values. I can also call object["0"] and object["1"]. Next, if I declare:

```
var object = {"0":0, "1":1}
```

I can also make all four of the above calls. But if I declare:

```
var object = {a:0, 1:1}
```

I get a ReferenceError of "a is not defined" when I call object[a], but object["a"] returns 0, even though the property name in the declaration is not a string. I guess JavaScript thinks I'm calling a variable that doesn't exist in the first example. But why do calling object[0] and object["0"] both work? It seems that JavaScript is doing some kind of automatic conversion for numbers (presumably since they can't be variable names), but what are the rules for this? And is this behavior universal to other places it might come up or just to the bracket notation for objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use brackets, the expression **inside** the brackets is evaluated. What's the value of the expression

```
 a
```

??  Well, if "a" isn't a declared variable, it's nonsense.  When you use `.` notation, the identifier (and it **must** be an identifier) following the operator is treated as a string. It's just the way the language works.

Comment: By that logic, if I declared the object as {"0":0, "1":1}, obj[0] should not work since it returns as 0, not "0"? But the call does work...

Comment: No, that's not correct, @ZackGao. Property names are **always** interpreted as strings. That's true even for actual arrays!  Again, it's the way the language is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a `ReferenceError` for `object[a]` is because a literal `a` is a variable in javascript. `"a"` is a string containing the letter a.

You can use the dot notation `object.a` or the bracket notation with `object["a"]`

```
object.a;    //=> 0
object["a"]; //=> 0

object[1];   //=> 1
object["1"]; //=> 1
```

Or you can use a variable for access

```
var x = "a";
object[x];   //=> 0

var y = 1;
object[y];   //=> 1
```

Comment: I guess, my question is why does object["a"] work when the property I declared is named a, not "a". If JavaScript automatically converts my declaration from {a:0} to {"a":0}, why do object[0] and object["0"] both work, but object[a] does not?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

`a` there is a token which the engine assumes is a variable.

If you type `"a"` JS knows it's a string-primitive.
If you type `0`, JS knows it's a number-primitive.

So on top of `obj.a`, `obj["a"]`, `obj[0]`, `obj["0"]`, you can also say:

```
var a = 0;
obj[a]; // 0
```

Your app is exploding, because `a` hasn't been defined yet, and now you want to use it.

And yes, this is the expected behaviour.
What's inside of the brackets isn't seen as a "part" of the object -- it's a way of saying "give me the value of the object which is referenced by this key", where the key might be a number or string (or something that can be coerced into a string or number).

In the future, with maps and weakmaps, you would actually be able to use other objects/functions as keys as well.

```
var obj  = new Map(),
    func = function () { },
    el   = document.getElementById("myId");

obj[func] = 1;
obj[el]   = 2;
```

Right now, these things technically work...   ...but only because they're converted to their string values...  ...so if you had two functions which were written the same (but technically two different objects), you would overwrite values, currently.
Inside of a map, they'd be treated as separate objects.

Using DOM elements is even worse, right now, as it might be useful to store hundreds of those and bind references to them, so that you don't have to keep looking for them...  ...but for now, you need to make a unique ID number/key for each one, and store that, and remember the keys, and then create a child object to hold the data you want...

Whereas in the future, with maps, you could say:

```
var my_els = document.querySelector(".lots-of-els");

for (let el of my_els /* also the future */) {
    console.log( my_map_of_data[el].info );
}
```